# Make hash links work in Chrome with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, turbolinks

I am depeloping a Rails app with Turbolinks. And I am using links to URLs like `mysite.com/page#element`. The issue is that when I click this link from another page, like `mysite.com/anotherpage`, in Chrome I am being scrolled to the element but then the next moment scrolled back to the top of the page. This issue doesn't appear neither in Firefox nor in Opera. And it also doesn't appear with Turbolinks turned off. Is there any way to solve this problem for Chrome without rejecting Turbolinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using an outdated version of turbolinks. There was a [similar bug reported](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/278) and it was [fixed in a version 2 months ago](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/commit/3338684f6bf158bba45cbaa219a8c1426f5526c7) 
I would try to remove the specific version of turbo links you have referenced in your gem file.

```
gem 'turbolinks'
```

Instead of

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 1.2'
```

(Or whatever version you have running)

And then running

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: It was outdated but I have updated it just before posting this question and it didn't change anything... Oh, but I didn't restart my rails server. Thank you. I feel embarrassed.

Comment: Hm, Opera for Linux is several versions older then the one for win.., May be that's the problem...